# How does git know where to put the updated line in a cherrypick even though I modified the original file?

Tags: git

I forked a repo with a file that looks like this:

```
whatever
pizza
pasta
pesto
```

I then changed it to:

```
whatever
banana
pasta
pesto
```

And eventually an upstream commit changed it to:

```
whatever
pizza
pasta
cheese
pesto
```

And when I cherrypicked that commit, I had exactly what I wanted:

```
whatever
banana
pasta
cheese
pesto
```

And the question is... how does this process work?

That's crazy, I expected it to fail and say: "hey what is this file, I don't recognize it".

Comment: "context lines"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does this process work?

Cherry-pick is a *merge,* that's how.

It uses the commit *before* the cherry-picked commit (parent of "them") as the merge-base, diffs that with "them" and diffs it with "us", and enacts *both* diffs in a new commit created on top of "us". That's what merge logic *is*.

So if you diff

```
whatever
pizza
pasta
pesto
```

to:

```
whatever
banana
pasta
pesto
```

you see that `pizza` changed to `banana`. And if you diff

```
whatever
pizza
pasta
pesto
```

to:

```
whatever
pizza
pasta
cheese
pesto
```

you see that `cheese` was inserted between `pasta` and `pesto`. Can you enact *both* those changes? Yes!!! You get

```
whatever
banana
pasta
cheese
pesto
```

Which is exactly what you *did* get.

Comment: Incredibly smart. Amazing. Thanks!